# IIS HttpCompression Not Showing

Tags: iis, gzip

I have a server where we have some local sites setup. Im looking on activating gzip on my specific website, but unfortunately, i cannot see the HTTPCOMPRESSION part in the system.webServer Configuration Manager (although it is in the web config itself).

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like:

[image]

No httpCompression though. I looked at the server level configuration manager and it has the httpCompression part, but not on the Site level.

IIS v8.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For reference, to show the setting in the IIS Panel, we need to enable it in the appsettings config of IIS.

c:/windows/system32/inetsvr/config/applicationhost.config

Locate httpCompression and change the parameter for overrideModeDefault = "Deny" to Allow. This will make IIS apply your settings on site level.

Cheers!!!

Comment: I can see it, but can't disable brotli on the site level if it's enabled on the applicationhost level :(

Comment: Could you please provide the complete line of code for overrideModeDefault?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to enable Dynamic Compression in IIS. This is done from features, web server (IIS), Web Server, Performance, Dynamic Content Compression.