# Blazor Webassembly Brotli and Gzip compression on IIS

Tags: iis, compression, blazor, gzip, brotli

As a Blazor developer I don't think there is a good documentation on this topic.
I have uploaded a very simple Blazor webassembly(v5) website with only 1 page now it takes more than 20 seconds to load in browser. I tried to use compression based on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-5.0#brotli-and-gzip-compression-1) Microsoft doc and used the [web.config](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/main/aspnetcore/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly/_samples/web.config?raw=true) file suggested by the document.
I have also installed URL Rewrite module, [Microsoft IIS Compression](https://github.com/Microsoft/IIS.Compression), StaticCompresstionModule and [DynamicCopressionModule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpcompression/) and tried modifying the web.config's following lines but it did not worked at all :

**web.config :**

```
...
 <httpCompression  directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
    <scheme name="br" dll="%ProgramFiles%\IIS\IIS Compression\iisbrotli.dll" />
     <scheme name="gzip" dll="%ProgramFiles%\IIS\IIS Compression\iiszlib.dll" />
....
```

The result still is not compressed and here is my browser's developer tool screenshot :

[image]

This can be a problem for everyone who uses Blazor as the front-end.
**Can any one please provide a step-by-step working answer ?**

**Update : here is my final web.config (which does not work):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".blat" />
      <remove fileExtension=".dat" />
      <remove fileExtension=".dll" />
      <remove fileExtension=".json" />
      <remove fileExtension=".wasm" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".blat" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".dll" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".dat" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".wasm" mimeType="application/wasm" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />


 

      <mimeMap fileExtension=".js.gz" mimeType="application/javascript" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".dat.gz" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".dll.gz" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json.gz" mimeType="application/json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".wasm.gz" mimeType="application/wasm" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".blat.gz" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".html.gz" mimeType="text/html" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".css.gz" mimeType="text/css" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".ico.gz" mimeType="image/x-icon" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg.gz" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".js.br" mimeType="application/javascript" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".dat.br" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".dll.br" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json.br" mimeType="application/json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".wasm.br" mimeType="application/wasm" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".blat.br" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".html.br" mimeType="text/html" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".css.br" mimeType="text/css" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".ico.br" mimeType="image/x-icon" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg.br" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
    </staticContent>
 <rewrite>
      <outboundRules rewriteBeforeCache="true">
        <rule name="Add Vary Accept-Encoding" preCondition="PreCompressedFile" enabled="true">
          <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Vary" pattern=".*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" value="Accept-Encoding" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Add Encoding Brotli" preCondition="PreCompressedBrotli" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Content_Encoding" pattern=".*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" value="br" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Add Encoding Gzip" preCondition="PreCompressedGzip" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Content_Encoding" pattern=".*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" value="gzip" />
        </rule>
        <preConditions>
          <preCondition name="PreCompressedFile">
            <add input="{HTTP_URL}" pattern="\.(gz|br)$" />
          </preCondition>
            <preCondition name="PreCompressedBrotli">
            <add input="{HTTP_URL}" pattern="\.br$" />
          </preCondition>
          <preCondition name="PreCompressedGzip">
            <add input="{HTTP_URL}" pattern="\.gz$" />
          </preCondition>
        </preConditions>
      </outboundRules>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Serve subdir">
          <match url=".*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot\{R:0}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Rewrite brotli file" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)"/>
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" pattern="br" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="\.(js|dat|dll|json|wasm|blat|htm|html|css|ico|svg)$" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.br" matchType="IsFile" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.br" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Rewrite gzip file" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)"/>
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" pattern="gzip" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="\.(js|dat|dll|json|wasm|blat|htm|html|css|ico|svg)$" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz" matchType="IsFile" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.gz" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="SPA fallback routing" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot\" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <httpCompression>
      <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="application/octet-stream" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/wasm" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/font-woff" enabled="true" />
      </dynamicTypes>
      <staticTypes>
        <add mimeType="application/octet-stream" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/wasm" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/font-woff" enabled="true" />
      </staticTypes>
    </httpCompression>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: If it is accessed for the first time after deployment or after a period of idle time, it will indeed take a while to get a response. IIS needs to create a process to allocate CPU resources and memory space to the application, let the application run on the server first, and then cache resources such as css and script files to the client.

Comment: Why do you think it is not compressed?  Your screenshot shows 10MB transfer size for 24MB resources - something is therefore compressed. Have you checked the request/response for one of the dll files to see what compression your browser said it could accept and what the server responded with? Maybe share that as it is more useful than the overview alone.

Comment: @MisterMagoo because I have stopped the downloading in this photo and also the documentation says that if the dlls are compressed you should see either "br" or "gzip" in content-encoding of your browser.

Comment: Why does it take 20 seconds to load in the first place? What kind of website are you trying to build? Have you tried splitting your app into Lazy-Loaded Assemblies?

Comment: check the browser's initial HTTP request header, does it have Accept-encoding set to accept br, gzip, etc ?

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran the Accept-encoding is equal to : gzip, deflate

Comment: @Grizzlly thank you but that is something else, not my question.

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

Most likely you have a site misconfiguration issue in IIS. To confirm it, please check if your site configuration will load in `Configuration Editor`:

[image: error-in-configuration-editor]

1. Select your website
2. Double-click on `Configuration Editor`
3. Check if this gives you an error

Then work your way through the errors and eliminate them one by one by updating your site configuration.

The challenge is that it's hard to provide a universally working example since it depends on many unknowns: OS version, IIS version, existing configs, etc.

## Detailed steps

There are two ways for how it can be done: using IIS Compression scheme providers (Option 1) or using rewrites (Option 2).

### Prerequisites

Here is what I used for my setup:

- Windows 10 Pro
- IIS version 10.0
- Installed [URL Rewrite Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-5.0#install-the-url-rewrite-module-1)
- `Dynamic Content Compression` and `Static Content Compression` IIS features [are enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpcompression/#windows-8-or-windows-81) in `Turn Windows features on or off` dialog
- New Blazor app created with .NET5.0 `dotnet new blazorwasm`

### Option 1: Adding compression using IIS Compression scheme providers

1. [Install](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/iis-compression/iis-compression-overview#installation) Microsoft IIS Compression
2. Update your site configuration

   Note: it seems like the suggested [configuration](https://github.com/Microsoft/IIS.Compression) won't work by default in IIS. I had to remove some entries from it because they were duplicates of the entries in the IIS machine config.

Here is a configuration that finally worked for me:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".blat" />
      <remove fileExtension=".dat" />
      <remove fileExtension=".dll" />
      <remove fileExtension=".json" />
      <remove fileExtension=".wasm" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".blat" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".dll" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".dat" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".wasm" mimeType="application/wasm" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
    </staticContent>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Serve subdir">
          <match url=".*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot\{R:0}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="SPA fallback routing" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot\" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
    <httpCompression>
      <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="application/octet-stream" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/wasm" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/font-woff" enabled="true" />
      </dynamicTypes>
      <staticTypes>
        <add mimeType="application/octet-stream" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/wasm" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/font-woff" enabled="true" />
      </staticTypes>
    </httpCompression>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

### Option 2: Adding compression using rewrites

1. Download the [`web.config`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/main/aspnetcore/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly/_samples/web.config) provided in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-5.0#brotli-and-gzip-compression-1)
2. Go through similar activities as above, eliminating all `web.config` inconsistencies.

   Note: In my case, I had to remove `mimeMap` for `.wasm` due to duplication reported by IIS:

   ```xml
   ...
   <staticContent>
     <remove fileExtension=".dll" />
     <remove fileExtension=".json" />
     <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
     <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
     <remove fileExtension=".wasm" /> <!-- added this line -->
     <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
     ...
   ```

### Results

And as a result, for either option, you should be able to see the following.

- for HTTP

  [image: result-http]
- for HTTPs

  [image: result-https]

Comment: Thank you I will check your answer tomorrow. If bounty expired I will add another bounty and give it to you.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work.

Comment: Interesting. So if you go with option 1, you can open a Configuration Editor? When you do, can you switch to `system.webServer/httpCompression` section? If you can, check the following properties: `(Collection)` should contain `br` and `gzip` schemes, `dynamicTypes` and `ststicTypes` should have correct `mimeTypes` listed (e.g. `application/octet-stream`, etc).

Comment: One more thing, sometimes IIS needs complete restart in order to apply the configuration. You can do that in Administrator command prompt by running `iisreset.exe /restart`.

Comment: it does not have httpCompression  section

Comment: If you don't see it, please make sure you have the corresponding IIS components installed in Windows. Specifically `Dynamic Content Compression` and `Static Content Compression`. See steps here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpcompression/#windows-8-or-windows-81

Comment: Now I fixed that using this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40802069/iis-httpcompression-not-showing 
and the collection does contain `br` and `gzip`  but it still doesn't work

Comment: I have added my final web config to the question

Comment: @nAviD In my `Option 1`  there was a missing `<urlCompression>` tag, answer updated. Can you please try adding this line `<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />` right before `<httpCompression>` tag in your config?

Comment: it didn't work too :(

Comment: Interesting. Since both `Option 1` and `Option 2` depend on correctly working URL Rewrite module, I would suspect that URL Rewrite does not work correctly. Maybe try enabling [Failed Request Tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) and see if this will clarify the situation?

Comment: Just realized that URL Rewrite was not mentioned in prerequisites. Sorry about that, fixed

Comment: I had added the Rewrite tag but it doesn't work too

Comment: What I meant is URL Rewrite is a module that needs to be installed [from here](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite). Just making sure you installed it. (requires `iisreset /restart`)

Comment: As I mentioned in the question I have installed it.

Comment: Ah, indeed. Sorry. Unfortunately it is difficult to troubleshoot IIS, especially over SO. I suspect that somehow Rewrite module does not work correctly, so I would try to confirm it with a separate website in the same IIS instance.

Comment: this is a test and try server it has nothing but this website on IIS. Everything is in the default settings.

Answer (score 1):

I started investigating the problem using this topic, and this is by far the best web.config I found:
https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/main/aspnetcore/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly/_samples/web.config
It worked like a charm: the initial loading time (no browser cache) was shorted from ~20 seconds to ~1.2 seconds. My configuration is as above: IIS hosted Blazor client application.

Comment: You should add more detail why your link answers this question

Comment: Please, format your link

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to follow prerequisites steps that Sasha mentioned.
After compression already set on server, modify the web.config using web.config mentioned in options 2.

Don't forget add this line in your web.config

```
<remove fileExtension=".wasm" />
```

Before I added the above, my apps got an error when loading.

After that, you can clear your browser cache and history to test it.